# Why can't I get a hidden field vaule in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I try to use the following code to get the value `"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG"`, but the result is null, why?

**Js Code**

```
    $('.CssRename').click(function () {
        var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);                    
        alert("My: "+fileName);

    });


function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
    return $(obj).parent().prevAll().first().val();
}
```

**Html Source**

```
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />

                <div class="leftli">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span> 
                </div>

                <div class="rightli">
                    <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
                    <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
                    <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span>
                    <span class="CssRename">Rename</span>
                    <span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                </div>
                <div class="middleli"><span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span><span class="filesize">66 KB</span></div>
            </li>
```

**And more , the Html Source can get the correct result**

```
        <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />

                    <div class="rightli">
                        <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
                        <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
                        <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span>
                        <span class="CssRename">Rename</span>
                        <span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span> 
                    </div>


                    <div class="middleli"><span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span><span class="filesize">66 KB</span></div>
                </li>
```

Comment: how can you click a hidden field?

Comment: I don't click hidden field, I use $('.CssRename').click(function () to click rename button

Comment: i just noticed it provided a demo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(obj).parent().prevAll().first().val();` => `$(obj).parent().siblings().first().val();`

```js
   $('.CssRename').click(function () {
        var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);                    
        alert("My: "+fileName);

    });


function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
    return $(obj).parent().siblings().first().val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />

    <div class="leftli">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span>
    </div>

    <div class="rightli">
      <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
      <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
      <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span>
      <span class="CssRename">Rename</span>
      <span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="middleli"><span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span><span class="filesize">66 KB</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that the result of siblings() is ordered?

Comment: You are welcome, I think so but I can't find it in documentation. You can add $(obj).parent().siblings(":hidden").first().val(); and don't care about ordering.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.CssRename').click(function() {

  var $this = $(this).closest("li").find("input.hidden");//this will be the idden field
  var fileName = GetHiddenFilename($this);
  alert("My: " + fileName);

});


function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
  return $(obj).val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />

    <div class="leftli">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span>
    </div>

    <div class="rightli">
      <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
      <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
      <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span>
      <span class="CssRename">Rename</span>
      <span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="middleli"><span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span><span class="filesize">66 KB</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Change your selector to match hidden field right away

1. Note i added class into the hidden input

```js
$('.CssRename').click(function () {
        var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);                    
        alert("My: "+fileName);

    });


function GetHiddenFilename(obj) {
    return $(obj).closest("li").find("input[type=hidden]").val();//use attribute selector with closest
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />

    <div class="leftli">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span>
    </div>

    <div class="rightli">
      <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
      <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
      <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span>
      <span class="CssRename">Rename</span>
      <span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="middleli"><span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span><span class="filesize">66 KB</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Use attribute selector to select the hidden field
2. Use `.closest()` with li parameter to select parent li

Comment: Thanks! 
It seems that it should be "return $(obj).parent().prevAll().last().val()", right ?

Comment: The first element is last() when I use prevAll() ?

Comment: yes because it is the last previous element the div with class `leftli` being the first previous

Comment: as stated in the docs `Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.` where hidden input is the last preceding siblings @HelloCW